# temporary file location on $_FILES

Tags: php

i created an upload card name, type ,description and picture.
Here are the files

```
<?php
$labels=array("type"=>"type",
                "CardName"=>"Card Name",
                "Description"=>"Description",
                "atk"=>"Attack",
                "def"=>"Defend");

    echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='InsertCard.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<h2>Insert new card </h2>";
    foreach($labels as $keys =>$values)
    {
        echo "$values <input type='text' name='$keys'/><br/>";
    }
    //echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='80000'/>";
    echo "Insert card <input type='file' name='pix' /><br/>";
    echo "<input type='submit'  value='insert new cards'/>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='return' value='return'/>";
    echo "</form>";

?>

<?php
$labels=array("type"=>"type",
                "CardName"=>"Card Name",
                "Description"=>"Description",
                "atk"=>"Attack",
                "def"=>"Defend");

if(@isset($_POST['return']))
{
    header("Location:ShowCatalog.php");
}
include("connect.inc");
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname) or die("can't connect to server");

foreach($_POST as $keys =>$values)
{
    if(empty($values))
    {
        if($keys=='type' or $keys=='CardName' or $keys=='Description' or $keys=='picture')
        {
            $empty_values[]=$keys;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($keys=='type')
        {
            if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z -]{4,15}$/",$values))
            {
                $invalid_data[]=$keys;
            }
        }
        elseif($keys=='CardName')
        {
            if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z '-]{4,30}$/",$values))
            {
                $invalid_data[]=$keys;
            }
        }
        elseif($keys=='Description')
        {
            if(!preg_match("/^[\"\:\(\);A-Za-z0-9., '-]{4,1000}$/",$values))
            {
                $invalid_data[]=$keys;
            }
        }
        elseif($keys=="atk" or $keys=="def")
        {
            if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{3,5}$/",$values))
            {
                $invalid_data[]=$keys;
            }
        }
        elseif($keys=='picture')
        {
            if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9., '-]{4,30}(.jpg)$/",$values))
            {
                $invalid_data[]=$keys;
            }
        }

    }
}
// i think i did something wrong here.
foreach($_FILES['pix'] as $keys =>$values)
{
        //if there is no file uploaded
    if($keys=='tmp_name')
    {
        if($value="")
        {
            $invalid_pix[]="can not find picture<br/>";
        }
    }
    //if the file is not jpeg format
    if($keys=='type')
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^image\/jpeg$/",$values))
        {
            $invalid_pix[]="only jpeg files are allowed<br/>";
        }
    }
    // if the file size is over 80000
    if($keys=='size')
    {
        if($values>=80000)
        {
            $invalid_pix[]="size is over than allowed";
        }
    }
}



if(@sizeof($empty_values)>0 or @sizeof($invalid_data)>0 or @sizeof($invalid_pix)>0)
{
    if(@sizeof($empty_values)>0)
    {
    $join=join(", ",$empty_values);
    $msg="You forgot to input: $join<br/>";
    echo $msg;
    }
    if(@sizeof($invalid_data)>0)
    {
    $join=join(", ",$invalid_data);
    $msg="Invalid data: $join";
    echo $msg;
    }
    if(@sizeof($invalid_pix)>0)
    {
        foreach($invalid_pix as $values)
        {
            echo $values."<br/>";
        }
    }
    echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='POST'>";
    echo "<h2>Insert new card </h2>";
    foreach($labels as $keys =>$values)
    {
        echo "$values <input type='text' name='$keys'/><br/>";
    }
    //echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='80000'/>";
    echo "Insert card <input type='file' name='pix' /><br/>";
    echo "<input type='submit'  value='insert new cards'/>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='return' value='return'/>";
    echo "</form>";
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo 'ok';
}
```

However, I'm getting a problem that i can not out put the value "can not find picture". I mean when user doesn't insert the card and press submit i always showed up "only jpeg files are allowed" but now "can not find picture". How to fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling mistake 
you used `$value` instead of `$values` in if condition

Check it out,.

```
    //if there is no file uploaded
if($keys=='tmp_name')
{
    if($value="")
    {
        $invalid_pix[]="can not find picture<br/>";
    }
}
```